# Event Handling in Javascript using Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to enable Event Handling in JavaScript. This is what I have so far:

```
function Field(args) {
    this.id = args.id;

    this.name = args.name ? args.name : null;
    this.reqType = args.reqType ? args.reqType : null;
    this.reqUrl = args.reqUrl ? args.reqUrl : null;
    this.required = args.required ? true : false;
    this.error = args.error ? args.error : null;

    this.elem = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.value = this.elem.value;

    this.elem.addEventListener('onblur', this, false);
    this.elem.addEventListener('click', this, false);
    this.elem.addEventListener('change', this, false);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.elem.value));

}

function FormTitle(args) {
    Field.call(this, args);
}

Field.prototype.getValue = function() { return Helpers.trim( this.value ) };

Field.prototype.sendRequest = function () {

};

Field.prototype.click = function (value) {
    alert("click");  
};

Field.prototype.onblur = function (value) {
    alert("onblur");  
};

Field.prototype.change = function (value) {
    alert("change");  
};

Field.prototype.dblclick = function (value) {
    alert("dblclick");  
};

Field.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
    case "click": this.click(this.value);
    case "onblur": this.onblur(this.value);
    case "change": this.change(this.value);
    case "dblclick": this.dblclick(this.value);
    }
};

// inheritProtootype uses parasitic inheritance to inherit from the Field's prototype
// and then assign the results to FormTitle's prototype.
inheritPrototype(FormTitle, Field);

var title = new FormTitle({name: "sa", id: "title"});
```

For some reason however, all events are triggered at the same time. For example, when I click on the Title field in the Form, instead of only Click event triggering, all four events are triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.elem.addEventListener('…', this, false);` does attach the `Field` instance, an object, as event listener - which needs to be a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `switch` statements misses some `break` statements, so in case `click` all four methods would be executed.

However, there's a better option than a `switch`-statement:

```
Field.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    var prop = event.type;
    if (prop in this) // && typeof this[prop] == "function"
        this[prop](this.value);
};
```

which will work for all events without explicitly mentioning them.

Comment: Yep, that worked like a charm. By the way, would you know why the 'onblur' event isn't triggering?

Comment: @user: Because the event is named `blur` :-) The `on` prefix is only for M$ `.attachEvent` and event-properties.

Comment: Thanks! Derija93 suggested the same and blur worked. But it (blur) seems to be triggered multiple times, including when I first focus on the field also. It is then also triggered when I switch windows. Do you know how I can fix that? By the way, is this approach to event handling good? Since you are an expert, I thought I'd ask. :)

Comment: @user This approach of event handling is definitely better than a `switch`. To explain what this piece of code does: the `in` keyword checks if the property denoted to the left exists in the specified object to the right. JavaScript allows accessing of properties in 'dot notation' and index notation. Using index notation, it is possible to dynamically access properties of an object by means of a variable. This effective approach allows for simple expansion of events without having to modify a list or so.

Comment: @user By the way, index notation is somewhat different from dot notation. Also index isn't quite the right word as the notation rather works like a map. Basically anything, including objects, can serve as key. This also means that you can have properties named `foo bar` which is impossible for dot notation. So quite a nice feature...

Comment: @Derija93: That type of member operator is named [*bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) (only with numbers I'd call it *index*). And no, it works only for string; everything you pass in is implicitly stringified

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I wasn't sure anymore how it's named. :) The stringify thing would explain why it worked with my objects when I randomly found out about it. I didn't do a lot of testing though and never needed objects as keys in a map...

Comment: @user: Now, `blur` is triggered every time when the user's focus leaves the input (including tab switches etc). If you don't want that, maybe you're looking for another event. What do you need it for?

Comment: Oh ok. I meant the use of prototypal inheritance for event handling in general. I suppose the new objects inheriting from the parent object will also inherit all the events. Is there a way to make sure new objects do not inherit all the events from the parent?

Comment: Actually, blur was triggered on focus. However, when I added the actual focus event, it fixed the issue. Weird, right?

Comment: @user You could filter those event handlers you don't want on subclasses, since you are using that custom `inheritPrototype` function. Maybe delete them again... Seems like some more hardcoding though. Maybe Bergi has a solution...

Comment: @user: I don't know how exactly you are applying prototypical inheritance here, and what you would need it for. I mean, surely there are use cases like in the composite pattern, but I don't know whether that does apply to your situation. I think it would be better if you'd ask a separate question which focuses on the prototypical inheritance (include your `FormTitle` and `inheritPrototype` functions!) and where you describe your goals, and the thoughts which have you led to this pattern

Comment: Makes sense. Btw, I just confirmed that unless the focus event is specifically added, blur is triggered when the field is on focus. ANy explanations guys?

Comment: Question posted. :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612462/blur-event-triggered-on-focus

Answer (score 3):

Simple. At the end of each of your `case` blocks, separate it from every succeeding block with a `break;` statement.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I am not sure what I was thinking! But Bergi's seems more elegant than the switch statement. So I chose that as the answer. By the way, would you know why 'onblur' event might not be triggering?

Comment: @user Perhaps because, when registering using listeners, you omit the 'on'. So try `addEventListener('blur', ...);` only.

Comment: Ok so that blur worked. But last question. It (blur) seems to be triggered multiple times, including when I first focus on the field also. It is then also triggered when I switch windows. Would you know a solution to that?

Comment: @user Sorry, don't know an answer to that. The switching windows part seems legit though since the field actually is blurred when quitting focus on the browser. However, it is unusual to have the event triggered when focusing the field...

Answer (score 1):

In your switch statement, you need to have a `break` after each case.

```
switch (event.type) {
  case "click": this.click(this.value); break;
  case "onblur": this.onblur(this.value); break;
  case "change": this.change(this.value); break;
  case "dblclick": this.dblclick(this.value); break;
}
```

The last break isn't needed but it's good practice to include it because you might add additional cases.

Comment: You have the right answer but Bergi's solution is so elegant. Thanks!