# Blur event triggered on focus

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am using the following code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsKQq/):

```
function Field(args) {
    this.id = args.id;

    this.name = args.name ? args.name : null;
    this.reqType = args.reqType ? args.reqType : null;
    this.reqUrl = args.reqUrl ? args.reqUrl : null;
    this.required = args.required ? true : false;
    this.error = args.error ? args.error : null;

    this.elem = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.value = this.elem.value;

    this.elem.addEventListener('blur', this, false);
    this.elem.addEventListener('focus', this, false);
}

// FormTitle is the specific field like a text field. There could be many of them.
function FormTitle(args) {
    Field.call(this, args);
}

Field.prototype.getValue = function() { return Helpers.trim( this.value ) };

Field.prototype.blur = function (value) {
    alert("blur");  
};

Field.prototype.focus = function (value) {
    alert("focus");  
};

Field.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    var prop = event.type;
    if ((prop in this) && typeof this[prop] == "function")
        this[prop](this.value);
};

inheritPrototype(FormTitle, Field);
var title = new FormTitle({name: "sa", id: "title"});

function inheritPrototype(e, t) {
    var n = Object.create(t.prototype);
    n.constructor = e;
    e.prototype = n
}

if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function (e) {
        function t() {}
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            throw new Error("Object.create implementation only accepts the first parameter.")
        }
        t.prototype = e;
        return new t
   }
}
```

The problem is that the 'blur' event is fired every time the field is brought to focus, which is opposite of what you'd expect. This is despite the fact that the focus event isn't even mentioned in the code. The problem is that I cannot replicate this problem in jsFiddle but the problem is happening in IE.

Also, on jsFiddle, there is another problem. The focus event is triggered multiple times...

Is there a possible explanation for this and/or a solution?

### Updated:

Bonus question (and last on this, promise).
I added a function addEvent to dynamically add events to form fields instead of adding them all directly in the parent constructor. This is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3r9M/) for it. I am trying to call the function but it doesn't seem to work. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: You are aware that when you click around, one Field's `focus` is another field's `blur` right?

Comment: What exactly is `inheritPrototype`?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Right, but other fields' objects are not created yet and events for them are not triggered.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, inheritPrototype uses constructor stealing to inherit parent properties and pass them on to the child. 
Please see updated question.

Comment: What is that `object` function? And what is that `FormTitle` function? You might only include the relevant parts, not all the duplicated `click`/`blur`/`change`/`dbclick` methods (just indicate there are more of them)

Comment: Um, didn't you want to ask about prototypical inheritance and not about that `blur` problem`? Since for that, you should post a complete, working example that demonstrates the issue (maybe also a http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @user - I removed `object(...)` and now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/94BVB/ It might be because you didn't copy the entire prototype, causing it to fail.

Comment: @Bergi, I have edited the question and included the jsFiddle link. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, if we remove Object, what can I use instead?

Comment: @user - Instead of `var n = Object.create(t.prototype);`, `var n = t.prototype;` seems to work fine.

Comment: Can you look at the second fiddle I added in the question please? And, thanks so much! I have spent hours on this! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `alert` in your `focus` handler immediately removes focus away from the field as soon as it gains focus.  The loss of focus triggers the `blur`.  It is odd that the `blur` comes first.

If you change the alerts to `console.log` (or something that does not steal focus), you will see that the events fire correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/rsKQq/4/

Comment: Yes, that is right. It works now. By the way, can you please look at the updated question? Specifically, the [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p3r9M/). I am trying to dynamically add events to the prototype objects using the addEvents method instead of assigning all events in the parent constructor. But it doesn't seem to be working. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: You're passing `focus` as the parameter when there is no variable named `focus`.  I believe you want to pass the string `"focus"`.  http://jsfiddle.net/p3r9M/1/

Comment: Wow, I sure need some coffee, like right now! Thanks so much, James! As an expert, do you have any comments on this approach (prototypal) to event handling?